# Using MQL with Google Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) Alerting Policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I have used [MQL](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference) to create charts in Google Cloud Monitoring that are a ratio of two metrics.

I would like to create an alerting policy based on the MQL, but the UI in Cloud Console does not have a query editor, like it does in Metrics Explorer.

Is there a way to use MQL when defining conditions for alerting policies using Google Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver)?

Comment: I have looked through Google Documentation and not found anything like that which you have described. This may still be something that Google is working on currently.

Comment: There is a Feature Request for MQL-based alerts in https://issuetracker.google.com/157770220

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Creating alerts with MQL is now supported :)* Both in UI and API.

---

1. To create a valid alert - pipe either [`condition`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#condition-tabop) or [`absent_for`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/reference#absent_for-tabop) keyword* at the end of your query. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/alerts for documentation.
2. For ratio alerts, follow the tips from regular ratio queries
   https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/examples#qlx-ratio-ratio
3. There are two major difference compared to dashboards - all MQL alerts must be saved in strict-form, and most of the conditions will need to have units-of-measure specified. See https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api#ql-alert-condition

---

) * - they are technically "*table operators*", not "*keywords*".

Answer (score 3):

Quoting c69:

> There is a Feature Request for MQL-based alerts in issuetracker.google.com/157770220

As at the date of this post, MQL-based alerts are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but you could create a custom service and then define an SLO for it using the ratio of two metrics.  You could then create an error budget burn alert.

```
"requestBased": {
    "goodTotalRatio": {
      "totalServiceFilter": "metric.type=\"appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_count\" resource.type=\"gae_app\" resource.label.\"module_id\"=\"default\"",
      "goodServiceFilter": "metric.type=\"appengine.googleapis.com/http/server/response_count\" resource.type=\"gae_app\" resource.label.\"module_id\"=\"default\" metric.label.\"response_code\"=\"200\"",
    }
  }
```

https://medium.com/google-cloud/slos-with-stackdriver-service-monitoring-62f193147b3f